# How does NSwag works in ASP.Net Zero framework?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, angular8, nswag

I tried working on an ASP.Net Zero and it works and I have used its built in PowerTools to create CRUD functionalities of the system. And I tried adding some manual front-end Angular UI in the client side of the application. I'm just not sure what will happen if I run the "refresh.bat" command in NSwag if it will erased all of my manually created UI and service proxies. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a git branch and examine changes after you try it.  Discard all if not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh.bat will update and generate service proxy for implemented api on .Net backend.
Always let your Api server running whenever u want to run refresh.bat.

Comment: Refresh.bat will not delete your existing proxies. It creates new proxy if a. Changes in the backend